# gmaven/groovy call script function from another script

Tags: maven, groovy, gmaven

I wonder if it is possible to call script's function (without classes) from within no-classes-script/maven plugin declaration?

For example script `callMe.groovy`:

```
def foo(){  
    println "hello"  
}
```

And this is the dunction I want to call from maven/another acript.
Is this possible without making classes?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Groovy Script is saved as class. So you have two ways to call the method from a script in another.

```
//Script Foo.groovy
def foo(){  
    println "hello"  
}

//Script Baz.groovy
def static baz(){
    println "static hello"
} 

//Script Bar.groovy
new Foo().foo() //prints hello
Baz.baz() //prints static hello
```